# Is this regarded as an elliptical sentence? It strikes me as weird

Tags: sentence-structure, syntax, terminology

My English teacher said this is not a complete sentence:

> I like white and yellow colours, so are my clothes.

She completed my sentence with a few more words in red colour:

> I like white and yellow colors, so are my clothes are these colours.

I have learnt of some elliptical sentences,
but I have never seen any example
sentences that are written that way (the 2nd sentence).

Can you tell me what kind of grammar / sentence construction it is, please?
I want to learn more about it.

Comment: Please don't tag your questions as [grammar], because it's an officially a deprecated tag. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of the sentences is correct.

It would be correct simply to state:

> > I like white and yellow colours/colors.

But then you need to link this sentence to the clause about your clothes:

> > I like white and yellow colours, so my clothes are these colours

omitting the first *are* ahead of *my clothes*.

Alternatively, you might write:

> > I like white and yellow colours, so my clothes are white and yellow.

To write: *So are my clothes* is a way of starting to ask a question about your clothes.

To write: *So my clothes are* is a way of starting to make a statement about your clothes.

An *elliptical sentence* is a sentence in which some information, that is missing from the sentence, is understood. You will find many examples if you search online.

Comment: Thank you Ronald Sole for your help. I have read your answer, but I am not quite sure if I can understand it. You wrote in your answer, "To write: So are my clothes is a way of starting to ask a question about your clothes.", what about this sentence, "Tom likes apples, so do I.", does this mean that I am ask a question about apple? (But I do like apples.)

Comment: @kitty The issue arises here because the word *so* can act in different ways. It can be one of several parts of speech. In your example, *so do I" means *I do as well* where so acts as an adjective. But you could also write: *So, do I look OK in this dress? Or: *So are my clothes suitable?* You are asking a question. Here *so* in an interjection leading to a question. It depends on the context.

Comment: @RonaldSole This may be nitpicking, but isn't *so* in your example actually an adverb (not an adjective)?  "Tom likes apples, so do I" means the same as "Tom likes apples, and I similarly do," and *similarly* is definitely an adverb, modifying 'do [like].'  I believe that *so* modifies 'do [like]' as well, and not the pronoun 'I'.